# Am I using mysqli_real_escape_string correctly?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm escaping a string using the OOP method of `mysqli_real_escape_string`. I saved the input being entered into a session variable to make sure it's escaping correctly. It seems to be escaping correctly, but when I check what gets entered into the database I don't see the slashes before single and double quotes.

So in the browser I echo:

```
Array
(
    [formContent] => I\'m always here!
)
```

But in the database I see:

```
I'm always here!
```

Does this mean there's something wrong with my code somewhere?

Comment: Does the query break? If not, it means escaping works. btw, the slashes are added "internally" at query execution time, not on the data itself, so you won't see them in your database. Sidenote: since you're using mysqlI, you should look into query parametrization, instead of manually escaping your inputs.

Comment: That's how it works. Nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: @DamienPirsy No, the query doesn't break. My content gets entered correctly otherwise. Just wanted to make sure I'm doing it right. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @heyjohnmurray it was a rethorical question :), I know the query didn't break

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's normal. `mysqli_real_escape_string` automatically escape the single quote for you.

When you have the string,

```
I'm always here!
```

`mysqli_real_escape_string` processed it as

```
I\'m always here!
```

so it will be saved on the database. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

> [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement, taking into account the current charset of the connection

what it does it escape single quote (save from sql injection at some level)

```
hello 'world
```

`mysqli_real_escape_string` processed it as

```
hello \'world
```

you can use `stripslashes` to remove `\`

Comment: If you find yourself *needing* to use `stripslashes`, something has gone horribly wrong.